# Linux software executable distribution path issue

Tags: linux, dependency-management, rhel, software-distribution

I am working on my software packing and distribution, as of now I don't know much about this, my software codes are using some perl modules like `linux statistics` and some `oracle` modules. So that I have kept **perl source** and all **module source** inside my software package.

In installing machine I will configure my perl based on user path(  `./Configure --prefix=customer_own_dir`), and install all perl modules in that `perl`. After that I will do

```
sed s~perl-place-holder~PERL_PATH~g *.checker.pl
```

this will replace all perl script( my custom codes) files to refer current perl dir ie,. `customer_own_dir/perl/bin/perl`. Now I want to make it as executable binary to deliver customer(To avoid configuring and building in customer end ), so that I should solve path dependencies in all perl binaries. Because while configuring perl source, `prefix` is hard coded in all files inside perl executable.

How to solve this issue, I couldn't find a proper wiki to do this? some sites describes `LD_PATH` and `ORIGIN`, I could not get that!!. Could any one explain a way to do this??

EDIT:

**Note:** Some of my libraries are dependent to particular perl version(5.14), also installing my modules in remote machine's existing perl needs root privilege to do that, some times I don't have access to root!

Comment: Do you modify Perl in any way? If not, don't include Perl in your distribution and just use the system's Perl version.

Comment: @rubenvb please see updated question!

Comment: you need to understand that Linux is not an OS. Every distribution has its own way of handling dependencies, and really the only way to properly handle distribution of your software is by creating proper packages for each distro you want to support. That being said, you should also be able to distribute a binary blob, including your custom perl, if you tell perl to look in your custom locations, cfr [here](http://perlmaven.com/how-to-change-inc-to-find-perl-modules-in-non-standard-locations).